# My country is missing from the Countries Options in merchant location dropdown menu

Tags: country-regions, merchant

I am looking for "Jordan" as the merchant location in the Countries Options dropdown list, but it is not there!  It was in My previous version of 1.8
Any ideas on how to add it?  Is this related to the Arabic language pack that my developer has not installed yet?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @Zaid, welcome! Can you please be more specific about what you are referring to with "_merchant location in the Countries Options dropdown list_" (maybe just add a screenshot of that section you're talking about)? "Jordan" is available by default. Also, when referring to your previous version, what may be your current then?

Answer (score 0):

Installing the Arabic language pack might help.

Also check for your country code in directory_country table. My sample database has JO - JOR